# Assign correct value from file to parameter

Tags: c++

I'm using C++ to read a file and assigning values from the file to parameters but the float numbers are no shown correctly when I cout the parameter value . Is the problem with the cout or with the actual value assigned to parameter? For instance, 21599.760000 is shown as 21599.8

Comment: Hard to say since can't see any of the code.

Comment: Either or. Please, provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to be precise without some code example. For future questions it's best to share a minimal code example.

Reading from

> 21599.760000 is shown as 21599.8

I assume it's the default precision being defined as 1.
The output precision for string conversion via `std::cout` can be defined with [std::setprecision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision).

For example `std::setprecision(3);` will let look 1.54321 like 1.543.

Comment: I changed the precision to 10 and the value is not shown as it should. For instance, 2276.188780 is shown as 2276.188721 in execution. Number 0.000000 is displayed as 0 only.

Answer (score 0):

The default precision of output streams is 6 so if you haven't changed the precision then you are printing the value with 6 significant digits. You can change the precision using `std::setprecision`.

---

Note that the actual value stored in `float` (probably) cannot be 21599.760000 because that value is not representable as a single precision IEEE-754 floating point number. The closest representable value is 21599.759765625. In this particular case, you can get ouput with same value as the input by using precision in range [7, 16].

Comment: I changed the precision to 10 and the value is not shown as it should. For instance, 2276.188780 is shown as 2276.188721 in execution. Number 0.000000 is displayed as 0 only.